# Table view not reloading after data is saved

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've created a basic chat app using a table view. When my users tap the 'send' button to deliver a message to another user, I want this tableview to refresh so that messages are displayed in real-time. That said, where I've placed [self.tableView reloadData] currently doesn't seem to be getting the job done. See code below:

```
- (IBAction)sendReply:(id)sender {


    NSMutableDictionary *nodeData = [NSMutableDictionary new];

    [nodeData setObject:@"messages" forKey:@"type"];


    NSDictionary *messageValues = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:self.replyText.text, nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"value", nil]];
    NSDictionary *finalMessage = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSArray arrayWithObject:messageValues] forKey:@"und"];

    [nodeData setObject:finalMessage forKey:@"body"];

     NSString *otherUID = [self.messageData objectForKey:@"targetuser"];


    NSString *userValue = otherUID;

    NSDictionary *targetMessage = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:userValue, nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"value", nil]];
    NSDictionary *finalUser = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSArray arrayWithObject:targetMessage] forKey:@"und"];

    [nodeData setObject:finalUser forKey:@"field_targetuser"];

    [nodeData setValue: @"Re:" forKey:@"title"];


    NSString *uid = [[[DIOSSession sharedSession] user] objectForKey:@"uid"];


    [DIOSNode nodeSave:nodeData success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {


          [self.tableView reloadData];


        MessageSentViewController *sentView = [[MessageSentViewController alloc] init];
        [self presentViewController:sentView animated:YES completion:nil];



    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Node did not save!");
    }];


}
```

Comment: `[self.tableView reloadData];` is being executed?

Comment: @Mr.UB If it's being executed, shouldn't it update my tableView? Eg. when a new message is posted to my server, and reloadData is executed, it should display the new post in my tableView no?

Comment: Are you updating your array with current data? I think table is reloading but data is not.

Comment: @Mr.UB Ahhh interesting. I thought reloading the tableView would update the array automatically. Is there a line of code I should be dropping in to update the array?

Comment: Nope, after sending message you have to fetch all messages again and then reload data.

Comment: @Mr.UB Done - thank you! :)

Answer (score -1):

Try to reload tableview on main/seprate thread